# Error with multiple fields in the form

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, post

I am creating a page where user enters the details through a registration form for a bank database. If the input values exits in the database then it is redirected to the next page. 
The problem associated with the code below is that when the user enters the details it redirects to the same registration page. The page is accessed through a separate file where the connection with the database is already established. No problem with the connection.
I have created a file 'index.php' which invokes the registration page and the php code shown below. another file core.php is referred to the index.php which contains the session_start().
The code works well when i am limiting the form to only two fields i.e cust_name & card_no. Please reply. Thanks in advance.
   Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    //require 'core.php';
    //echo $current_file;

    if (isset($_POST['cust_name']) && isset($_POST['card_no']) && isset($_POST['cvv']) && ($_POST['exp_month']) && ($_POST['exp_year'])) //error possibly in this part  
    {

               $cust_name = $_POST['cust_name'];
               $card_no = $_POST['card_no'];
               $cvv = $_POST['cvv'];
               $exp_month = $_POST['exp_month'];
               $exp_year = $_POST['exp_year'];

       if(!empty($cust_name) && !empty($card_no) && !empty($cvv) && !empty($exp_month) && !empty($exp_year)) //error possible in this part
       {
              $query = "SELECT id FROM bank WHERE cust_name='$cust_name', card_no='$card_no',cvv='$cvv', exp_month='$exp_month',exp_year='$exp_year' ";
              if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
              {
                $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
                 if($query_num_rows==0)
                 {
                   echo 'Invalid Card details';
                 }
                 else if($query_num_rows==1)
                 {
                   //echo 'OK!!';
                   $user_id = mysql_result($query_run,0,'id');
                   $_SESSION['user_id']=$user_id; //starts the session
                    header('Location:login2.php');/*redirects if the details are present in                  database*/        
                 }
              }      
        }   

        else
       {
           echo 'PLEASE ENTER DETAILS';
       } 
    }
    ?>


    <form action ="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method="POST">//registration form

    Card Name:<input type = "text" name = "cust_name"><br/>

    Card No:<input type = "text" name = "card_no"><br/>

    CVV:<input type = "text" name = "cvv"><br/>

    Expiry Month & Year<select name="exp_month"><br/>
    <option selected value="janauary">January</option>
    <option value="february">February</option>
    <option value="march">March</option>
    <option value="april">April</option>
    <option value="may">May</option>
    <option value="june">June</option>
    <option value="july">July</option>
    <option value="august">August</option>
    <option value="september">September</option> 
    <option value="october">October</option>
    <option value="november">November</option>
    <option value="december">December</option>
    </select>
    <select name="exp_year"><br/>
    <option selected value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
    <option value="2024">2024</option>
    <option value="2025">2025</option><br/>
    </select><br/>


    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    <input type="reset" value="reset"><br/> 

    </form>

<----index.php---->
<?php
require 'database.php'; //establishes database connection
require 'core.php'; //uses core.php
include 'login_form.php';//redirects to login_form
?>

<----core.php-----?
<?php
ob_start();
session_start(); // starts the session
$current_file = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];//used at login_form
?>
    --------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your IF statement works with two fields is because you can only have one && expressions in an IF statement in PHP. You're going to have to separate your && statements. Though, it would be better and safer if you just check each POST individually:

if ( isset($_POST['name'] ){}

Then run what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code. You do not have an 'else' clause to deal with the query failing. I also tend to use 'var_dump' and 'die('i am here') statements to ensure that the program is at least getting getting to the points i expect, when i expect it to.

I post the code i have, complete with 'debugging code' so that you can at least confirm that those tests are working correctly for yourself. They are working fine.

You should also exit the script after sending the headers to change location.

```
    var_dump($_POST);

    if (isset($_POST['cust_name']) && isset($_POST['card_no']) && isset($_POST['cvv']) && ($_POST['exp_month']) && ($_POST['exp_year'])) //error possibly in this part
    {

               $cust_name = $_POST['cust_name'];
               $card_no = $_POST['card_no'];
               $cvv = $_POST['cvv'];
               $exp_month = $_POST['exp_month'];
               $exp_year = $_POST['exp_year'];

   //       die('iam here '. __FILE__.__LINE__);
       if(!empty($cust_name) && !empty($card_no) && !empty($cvv) && !empty($exp_month) && !empty($exp_year)) //error possible in this part
       {
  //         die('i am here '. __FILE__.__LINE__);
              $query = "SELECT id FROM bank WHERE cust_name='$cust_name', card_no='$card_no',cvv='$cvv', exp_month='$exp_month',exp_year='$exp_year' ";
              if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
              {
                 $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
                 if($query_num_rows==0)
                 {
                   echo 'Invalid Card details';
                 }
                 else if($query_num_rows==1)
                 {
                   //echo 'OK!!';
                   $user_id = mysql_result($query_run,0,'id');
                   $_SESSION['user_id']=$user_id; //starts the session
                    header('Location:login2.php');/*redirects if the details are present in                  database*/
                    exit(); // should exit the script
                 }
              }
              else { // unmatched else
                 echo 'THE SQL QUERY FAILED';
              }
        }

        else
       {
           echo 'PLEASE ENTER DETAILS';
       }
    }
    ?>
```